# Solve this integral..

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$$\int_{}^{}{\frac{x^2}{e^x+1}}dx$$

I have tried this using by-parts method but I could not do the integration of the second function.

Comment: Why do you think that you can compute it ?

Comment: If you can do this in an easier way then do it.

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+x%5E2%2F%28e%5Ex%2B1%29&t=crmtb01) doesn't give an elementary primitive

Answer (score 3):

Set $e^x+1 \mapsto u$ then:
$$\int_{ }^{ }\frac{x^{2}}{e^{x}+1}dx=\int_{ }^{ }\frac{\left(\ln\left(u-1\right)\right)^{2}}{u\left(u-1\right)}du=\color{blue}{-\int_{ }^{ }\frac{\left(\ln\left(u-1\right)\right)^{2}}{u}du}+\color{red}{\int_{ }^{ }\frac{\left(\ln\left(u-1\right)\right)^{2}}{u-1}du}$$

- For the red part setting $\ln\left(u-1\right) \mapsto t$ yields:
  $$\int_{ }^{ }\frac{\left(\ln\left(u-1\right)\right)^{2}}{u-1}du=\int_{ }^{ }t^{2}dt=\frac{t^{3}}{3}+C=\color{red}{\frac{\left(\ln\left(u-1\right)\right)^{3}}{3}+C}$$

---

- For the blue part use [dilogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm):

$$-\int_{ }^{ }\frac{\left(\ln\left(u-1\right)\right)^{2}}{u}du$$$$=-\left(\left(\ln\left(u-1\right)\right)^{2}\ln\left(u\right)-2\int_{ }^{ }\frac{\ln\left(u\right)\ln\left(u-1\right)}{u-1}du\right)$$$$=-\left(\left(\ln\left(u-1\right)\right)^{2}\ln\left(u\right)-2\left(-\text{Li}_{2}\left(1-u\right)\ln\left(u-1\right)+\int_{ }^{ }\frac{\text{Li}_{2}\left(1-u\right)}{u-1}du\right)\right)$$

Now calculate $\int_{ }^{ }\frac{\text{Li}_{2}\left(1-u\right)}{u-1}du$:

Set $1-u \mapsto v$:
$$\int_{ }^{ }\frac{\text{Li}_{2}\left(1-u\right)}{u-1}du=\int_{ }^{ }\frac{\text{Li}_{2}\left(v\right)}{v}du=\text{Li}_{3}\left(v\right)=\text{Li}_{3}\left(1-u\right)+C$$

$$\therefore \;\;\;-\int_{ }^{ }\frac{\left(\ln\left(1-u\right)\right)^{2}}{u}du=\color{blue}{-\left(\left(\ln\left(u-1\right)\right)^{2}\ln\left(u\right)-2\left(-\text{Li}_{2}\left(1-u\right)\ln\left(u-1\right)+\text{Li}_{3}\left(1-u\right)\right)\right)+C}$$

---

The final answer would be :
$$\int_{ }^{ }\frac{x^{2}}{e^{x}+1}dx$$

> $$=\frac{\left(\ln\left(u-1\right)\right)^{3}}{3}-\left(\left(\ln\left(u-1\right)\right)^{2}\ln\left(u\right)-2\left(-\text{Li}_{2}\left(1-u\right)\ln\left(u-1\right)+\text{Li}_{3}\left(1-u\right)\right)\right)+C$$